# Connect to a wireless network before logging on (Windows 10)

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, windows-domain

I have a Windows 10 laptop that has been joined to a domain. The only networking option is wireless (no wired connection available). I am able to log onto the laptop with a user that previously logged on, but any new users are not able to - `Unable to find logon servers`. I am assuming it is disconnected from the wireless network.

Ideally, I'd like to allow a user to configure a wireless network before logging on, although even pre-configuring a wireless network and enabling it for all users is an acceptable 2nd option at this point.

I've tried [this approach](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/2047-enable-wireless-connection-pre-logon-on-domain) which didn't work, I still get the error. If I run `netsh wlan show profiles`, I get:

```
Group policy profiles (read only)
---------------------------------
     Mywirelessnet
```

I then used that in the registry key:

```
%comspec% /c netsh wlan connect name="Mywirelessnet"
```

Is there any other way to allow connecting to wireless networks before logging on?

Comment: Is there not a connection icon in the lower right of the login screen?

Comment: no, no connection icon, only ease of access and power.